# I train a full CNN on 3-D data and I get NaN in the training loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a full CNN on 3-D data(I use conv3D). First, some context to understand. the input is a 3-D matrix that represents the density map of a protein, and the output is a 3-D matrix where the locations of C-alpha is labeled as 1 and the rest is labeled as 0. As expected, this leads to a massive data imbalance. So I implemented a custom cross-entropy cost function that focuses the model on class=1 as shown below:
[custom cost function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrYyL.jpg)
these maps tend to be large, so the training time tends to increase exponentially with the slight increase in map dimension, or if I make my network a little deeper. In addition to that, a large part of the map is empty space, but I have to keep it to maintain real distance between different locations of C-alpha. To work around this problem, I split each map into smaller boxes of dimension (5,5,5). the benefit of this approach is I get to ignore the empty space which significantly reduces the amount of memory and computation needed for the training.
The problem that I have now is that, I get NaN in the training loss and the training is terminated as shown below:
[Network training behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0UqG.jpg)

this is the network I am using:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(15, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(5,5,5,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv3D(30, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv3D(60, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv3D(30, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv3D(15, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv3D(1, kernel_size=(3,3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
model.compile(loss=weighted_cross_entropp_loss, optimizer='nadam',metrics=['accuracy'])

############# model training ######################################
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=epochs, verbose=1,validation_split=0.2,shuffle=True,callbacks=[stop_immediately,save_best_model,stop_here_please])
model.save('my_map_model_weighted_custom_box_5.h5')
```

can anyone please help me, I have been working on this problem for many many weeks

Regards

Comment: Have you checked your data to make sure that the inputs are how they should be? This person on GitHub had a similar issue: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2134#issuecomment-268628635

Comment: My input is normalized when it is still a big map (80,80,80) or more. Then when I take the small boxes (5,5,5), I first check if the box is not empty by computing the sum of the box, if the sum is greater than 0 then the box is not empty so I keep it, otherwise, if it is empty I ditch it. So there should not be any empty or NaN boxes

Comment: I removed the early stopping condition and set the weight of class1 to 1. Now, I have the training loss decreasing and the validation loss increasing. I think this is a sign of over-fitting, so I am trying to reduce the size of the network and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

So I asked this question some time ago and since then I have been trying to find a solution to it. I think I managed to find it, so I thought I should share it. But before I do that I want to say thing that I read and I think it points to the core of my problem. the saying goes like this " if hyper parameter works for someone else, it does not necessarily work for you. If you are trying to solve a new problem using a new architecture, then you need new hyper parameters", or something along those lines.
Sadly, in Keras (which is a good tool by the way if used within the expected domain) it is stated that the optimizer parameters should be kept as they are, which is wrong, now to the solution.

### the short answer:

the learning rate was too high.

### the long answer:

here I detail how to figure that out. If you get a NaN within the first 100 iterations that is a straight indication that the problem is high learning rate. However, if you get it after the first 100 iterations, then the problem can be one of two things:

1. if you are using RCNN then you have to use gradient.clip
2. if you have a custom layer (I had a custom cost function) then it is likely the reason. Now, an important thing to keep in mind is, there is a difference between correct implementation and stable implementation. you can implement your custom layer correctly, However, there are some tricks that you need to add to make it stable which is what was missing from my custom layer.